# Why do I get a "cannot find module" error when doing a dynamic import in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamic-import

I'm trying to load in a JavaScript module dynamically at runtime and it's not playing ball. I've created a very simple barebones example, perhaps someone can explain where I'm going wrong.

I have a javascript file called "testModule.js" sitting in the folder "media".

```
const data={theString:"Hello baby"}

export default data
```

Then in my main project I have the following code:

```
export class StartImportTest extends Scene
{
    constructor() {
        super()
        var tURL = "media/testModule.js"
        const a= import(tURL).then(this.testImport)
    }
    testImport(a:any) {
        console.log(a, a.theString)
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get the error message `Cannot find module 'media/testModule.js'`

The url is definitely correct (I tried loading in a picture from that location instead, which worked fine), so perhaps the error is something to do with my webpack settings? But I'm not sure what to look for there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To indicate that module exists in a subfolder in the current folder, you should prepend `./` to url module's path

```
var tURL = "./media/testModule.js"
```

If module resides in a different folder then need to use `../` as many times as necessary to go up in the structure to get to the destination folder.

**update**

Webpack uses these paths to find dependencies and to build the bundle. So you should provide paths to the source file. Once the final build is created, these paths won't be used. So you'll be okay.

Comment: That didn't work, but adding ../../ did the job. It seems that the import statement needs to be relative to the *original source folder* of the TypeScript file, not its location in the final build. But now I'm unsure whether this is actually going to do what I need it to do! Still, at least I can move forward now.

Comment: This is only partially correct. From the type system perspective, Dynamic Imports follow the same module resolution rules as static Imports. So whether or not you need to use relative paths or Canon leverage a base URL depends on your typescript configuration which should match your loader or bundler configuration

Comment: Yes - meaning that as far as I can see there's not much point in using them. The whole reason I wanted to use dynamic importing was to be able to compile a project without including the dynamically imported code, so I can add modules later. But that seems to be impossible as far as I can tell. Right now I've been reduced to using `eval`!